# Quote from urllib.parse causing troubles in flask sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlite, flask, web, flask-sqlalchemy, urllib

I encountered a problem after implementing 'quote' method from 'urllib.parse'. For some reason the string genereted by quote is incorrecty read from sqlite databse, or incorrectly saved in the first place. And it happend only if string contains non ascii characters.

Full code https://github.com/TheNiska/MainWebSite/tree/main

```
@application.route('/article/<fname>')
def article(fname):
    content = Article.get_content(fname)  # tuple (id, text)
    if content is not None:
        article_info = Article.articles_dict[fname]
        return render_template("article.html", article_info=article_info,
                               content=content, fname=fname)
    else:
        return render_template("error.html", error_code="404",
                               error_text="Страница не найдена"), 404
...

class Article:
    ...
    @classmethod
    def get_content(cls, article_name):
        result = ArticleDB.query.with_entities(ArticleDB.id, ArticleDB.article)
        result = result.filter(
                    ArticleDB.translit_title == article_name).first()
        result = (str(result.id), result.article) if result else None
        return result

    @classmethod
    def init_from_db(cls):
        selected = ArticleDB.query.with_entities(
                   ArticleDB.title, ArticleDB.translit_title,
                   ArticleDB.creator, ArticleDB.description, ArticleDB.date
                   ).order_by(ArticleDB.date.desc())

        for record in selected:
            cls.articles_dict[record[1]] = (record[0], record[2],
                                            record[3], record[4])
    @classmethod
    def add(cls, title, content, username, descr):
        lat_title = translit(title, 'ru', reversed=True).lower() # using latin chars
        lat_title = lat_title.replace(' ', '-').replace("_", '-')
        lat_title = quote(lat_title) # this damn thing
        ...
        cls.articles_dict[lat_title] = (title, username, descr, date)

        articleDB = ArticleDB(title=title, translit_title=lat_title,
                              date=date, article=html_content,
                              description=descr,
                              creator=username)
        db.session.add(articleDB)
        db.session.commit()

...
class ArticleDB(db.Model):
    ...
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    title = db.Column(db.Unicode(200), unique=True, index=True)
    translit_title = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True, index=True)
    ...
    article = db.Column(db.UnicodeText)
...

# below how link is created in html-template
{% for key in articles %} # articles = Article.articles_dict
    <td><a href="{{url_for('article', fname=key) }}">{{ articles[key][0] }}</a></td>
{% endfor %}
```

Moreover, this problem only on the server. On my PC on develepment server everything works fine.
Help!

For exmaple, I created a new article with title "нь". When I clink on the link on my website it sends me to https://aldaron.ru/article/n%2527 and I sees 404 error. So to test what's happening I go through ssh in my server and run flask shell:

```
>>> from app.models import Article
>>> content = Article.get_content('n%2527')
>>> content
>>> type(content)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> content = Article.get_content('n%27') # for some reason works
>>> content
('8', '<p>джодл дж лд ж д</p>')
```

Ok, fine. For some reason it has become n%27. So now I try https://aldaron.ru/article/n%27, but it's still 404. OMG. I don't what's happenning.